# Push new value into array if property matches

Tags: javascript, arrays

1. Iterate through HTML items and push them into an array
2. If item name matches an object's name property already in the array, just add it's data into that object.

I tried looking through a few different answers but either end up with console errors or overwriting my existing data.

```js
var item = {};
var items = [];

$('li').each(function() {
    var itemName = $(this).find('.name').text();
    var itemData = $(this).find('.data').text();
    
    //for(var i = 0, lens = items.length; i < 1; i++) {
    //    if(items[i].name === itemName) {
    //         ?
    //    }
    //}

    item = {
        name: itemName,
        data: itemData
    }
    items.push(item);
});
```

```html
<li>
    <span class="name">Item 1</span>
    <span class="data">3</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="name">Item 1</span>
    <span class="data">6</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="name">Item 1</span>
    <span class="data">9</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="name">Item 2</span>
    <span class="data">3</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="name">Item 2</span>
    <span class="data">6</span>
</li>
```

Comment: You have to add jQuery to your page the `$` function is not javascript. And add jquery to the tags too, please

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini Thanks. This is just a sample.

Comment: If you want to have the existing data AND add new data then it sounds like data should be an array (or other container type).  Then you just item[i].data.push(newdata).

Comment: So this is not the error you have? Please provide the real error.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Please write a [mcve].

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini and DavidS thanks for trying anyways. Have an excellent day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will achieve your aim:

```
var items = {};

$('li').each(function() {
    var itemName = $(this).find('.name').text();
    var itemData = $(this).find('.data').text();

    items[itemName] = items[itemName] || [];
    items[itemName].push(itemData);
});

var result = Object.keys(items).map(function(name) {
  return {name: name, data: items[name]};
});

console.log(result);
```

**Update 1: (Add other properties)**

```
var items = {};

$('li').each(function() {
    var itemName = $(this).find('.name').text();
    var itemData = $(this).find('.data').text();

    items[itemName] = items[itemName] || {name: itemName};
    //Add data
    items[itemName].data = items[itemName].data || [];
    items[itemName].data.push(itemData);
    //Add other property
    items[itemName].time = Date.now();
});

var result = Object.keys(items).map(function(name) {
  return items[name];
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var item = {};
var items = {};

$('li').each(function() {
    var itemName = $(this).find('.name').text();
    var itemData = $(this).find('.data').text();
  
    items[itemName] = items[itemName] || [];
    items[itemName].push(itemData);
});

var result = Object.keys(items).map(function(name) {
  return {name: name, data: items[name]};
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <span class="name">Item 1</span>
    <span class="data">3</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="name">Item 1</span>
    <span class="data">6</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="name">Item 1</span>
    <span class="data">9</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="name">Item 2</span>
    <span class="data">3</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="name">Item 2</span>
    <span class="data">6</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Changing to best answer for conciseness, believe this runs faster as well.

Comment: I love conciseness. Good luck ;)

Comment: RBOUH would you be able to add an example of pushing additional properties in as well? Say there was another field such as name or data. May be helpful for folks finding this in the future.

Comment: Sure thing ! add the property to data or the object ?

Comment: I think it makes sense to add it to the object itself

Comment: Please check Update 1 and let me know if that' what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
var item = {};
var items = [];

$('li').each(function () {
    var itemName = $(this).find('.name').text();
    var itemData = $(this).find('.data').text();

    var add_new = true;
    for(var i = 0, lens = items.length; i < lens; i++) {
        if(items[i].name === itemName) {
            items[i].data.push(itemData);
            add_new = false;
        }
    }
    if (add_new) {
        item = {
            name: itemName,
            data: [itemData]
        }
        items.push(item);
    }
});
console.log(items);
```

Comment: There's the ticket. It was setting that variable of whether to add a new object or not that was throwing me off. Thank you!